# Odoo 10 XMl RPC question about passing arguments

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, xml-rpc

I have defined a function inside a custom model function.registry which looks like this:

```
   def change_date_planned_start(self, production_id, new_date):
        for function in self:
            production = self.env['mrp.production'].search([
                function.domain
            ])

            if production:
                production.date_planned_start = new_date
```

Inside my client I call this function like this:

```
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url), verbose=True)
models.execute_kw(
    db, uid, password, 'function.registry', 'change_date_planned_start',
    ['2714', '12.12.2021']
)
```

When i execute the client it gives me the error:

```
TypeError: change_date_planned_start() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [['2714', '12.12.2021']] instead of ['2714', '12.12.2021']

Comment: Thank you, I tried it with the same error

Comment: EDIT: This works but then in my function I can only have 
def change_date_planned_start(self, args) as arguments. The documentation for v10 api states that they are passed by position. I think the problem here is that self is also considered an argument so it passes the first number 2714 into self which I could see in the log. It should normally ignore self

Answer (score 0):

You should add a decorator `api.model` to method `change_date_planned_start`

```py
from odoo import api

@api.model
def change_date_planned_start(self, production_id, new_date):
    for function in self:
        production = self.env['mrp.production'].search([
            function.domain
        ])

        if production:
            production.date_planned_start = new_date
```

Comment: Thank you, the error still persists even with @api.model

Comment: @Florent If ```self``` is a null recordset,you could try [False,'2714', '12.12.2021'] instead of ['2714', '12.12.2021'].If self is not null,you could try [[1,2,3],'2714','12.12.2021'] instead of ['2714', '12.12.2021'].The [1,2,3] is ```ids``` of ```self```,it should be equal to ```self.ids```.